# django ratings along with one to one field

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

## models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    #fields here

class Food(models.Model):
    rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant)

class Service(models.Model):
    rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant)
```

## doubt

how am i suppose to integrate the food and service along with the restaurant model and also be able to rate them aswell , please help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    #fields here

class Food(models.Model):
    rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant)

class Service(models.Model):
    rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant)
```

Try:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    #fields here
    food_rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
    service_rating = RatingField(range=5, weight=5,can_change_vote = True,allow_delete = True,allow_anonymous = True)
```

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: oh , thanks , being a programmer this was kind of me being stupid asking such a question , thanks btw